# Solve $xy''+y'-xy=0$ using Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Using Frobenius method solve $$xy''+y'-xy=0$$

Comparing the given equation with $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$ we have,

$$P(x)=\frac{1}{x}\qquad Q(x)=-1$$

Here $x=0$ is a singular point of the given differential equation. Now
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x-0)P(x)&=1\\
 \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x-0)^2Q(x)&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence $x=0$ is a regular singular point. The indicial equation is,

$$
\begin{aligned}
r(r-1)+pr+q&=0\\
r^2-r+r&=0\\
r=0
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
 y'&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(k+r)x^{k+r-1}\\
 y''&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(k+r)(k+r-1)x^{k+r-2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Substituting these on the DE,

$$
\begin{aligned}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+r)(k+r-1)a_kx^{k+r-1}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+r)x^{k+r-1}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{k+r+1}&=0\\
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty ((k+r)(k+r-1)+(k+r))a_k x^{(k+r-1)} +\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{k-2}x^{(k+r-1)} &=0\\
 r^2a_0x^{r-1}+(r+1)^2a_1x^r+\sum_{k=2}^\infty [(n+r)^2a_n-a_{n-2}]x^{n+r-1} &=0
\end{aligned}
$$

$$r^2a_0=0\qquad (r+1)^2a_1=0\implies a_1=0$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
(n+r)^2a_n-a_{n-2} &=0\\
an&=\frac{a_{n-2}}{(n+r)^2}\\
{a_{n+2}}&=\frac{a_n}{(n+2+r)^2}\\
&=\frac{a_n}{(n+2)^2}\quad\text{ Using }r=0
\end{aligned}
$$

$a_3=a_5=\cdots=a_{2n+1}=0$ because $a_1=0$. Now,

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_2&=\frac{a_0}{2^2}\\
a_4&=\frac{a_2}{4^2}=\frac{a_0}{4^22^2}=\frac{a_0}{2^{2.2}(2.1)^2}\\
a_6&=\frac{a_4}{6^2}=\frac{a_0}{6^24^22^2}=\frac{a_0}{2^{2.3}(3.2.1)^2}\\
&\vdots\\
a_{2n}&=\frac{a_0}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

One solution of the DE is,

$$
y(x)=x^0(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k)=a_0(1+\frac{1}{2^2}x^2+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{2n}n!}x^{2n}+\cdots)
$$

what about another solution? How to get that one?

Comment: Its a typo @LutzLehmann. Fixed now.

Comment: In the summation you left out the square of the factorial. // See "reduction of order" to continue the solution and find the second solution containing a logarithmic term.

Answer (score 2):

The indicial equation has double root $r=0$.  So the second solution will involve $\log x$.

$$
y_1(x)=\,  \left(1+{\frac{1}{4}}{x}^{2}+{\frac
{1}{64}}{x}^{4}+\dots\right),
\\
y_2(x) =
\log(x) \left(1+{\frac{1}{4}}{x}^{2}+{\frac{1
}{64}}{x}^{4}+\dots \right) +\left(-{\frac{1}{4}}{x}^
{2}-{\frac{3}{128}}{x}^{4}+\dots\right) 
$$

---

Maple code

[image: code]

Comment: How to give mathematical argument for this solution? Because my lecturer didn't showed that method. @GEdgar. Like why $\log x$? Why not anything else?

Comment: This is part of the Frobenius method.  If the indicial equation has root $r=a$ then try a series of the form $x^a+\dots$.  This may fail for a second smaller root that differs from the larger root by an integer.  Then you may need a $\log x$ type series solution.  And (as here) if there is a multiple root $r=a$ of order $k$ you may need $k$ series with $y_1 = x^a+\dots$, $y_2 = (\log x)x^a+\dots$ and so on up to $y_k = (\log x)^{k-1}x^a+\dots$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method

Comment: Thanks(+1) for your response @GEdgar. But how you get $+\left(-{\frac{1}{4}}{x}^
{2}-{\frac{3}{128}}{x}^{4}+\dots\right) $ Like how to get $B_k$ in $y_2(x)=Cy_1\log x+\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k x^{k+r_1}?$

Comment: Same way as with the $a_k$ you did.  Substitute into the DE, collect coefficients, get equations to solve recursively.

Comment: Then the $Cy_1\log x$ term become trouble to me. Like $$y_2'=\frac{Cy_1}{x}+Cy_1' \log x+\sum_{k=0}^\infty k B_k x^{k-1}$$ and $$y_2''=\frac{Cy_1'}{x}-\frac{Cy_1}{x^2}+C\log xy_1''+\frac{Cy}{x}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}$$ $$x\frac{Cy_1'}{x}-\frac{Cy_1}{x^2}+C\log xy_1''+\frac{Cy}{x}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}+\frac{Cy_1}{x}+Cy_1' \log x+\sum_{k=0}^\infty k B_k x^{k-1}-x Cy_1\log x+\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k x^{k}=0$$Now it seems too terrify. @GEdgar

Comment: Now if we substitute the $y_1(x)=\left(1+{\frac{1}{4}}{x}^{2}+{\frac
{1}{64}}{x}^{4}+\dots\right)$ and try to collect the coefficient, then it become to much work. Even I was lost how to do that. Could you demonstrate it, please. Like how did you manage to get it in such a short time?

Comment: To get it in a short time, I told a computer to do it.

Comment: Which program you used to get the solution? Mathematica? I would like to know the program as well as it's code @GEdgar